# How to remove a row without refreshing and then gain new list of item in asp mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to remove row from table in html view without refreshing and then gain new table list. Here is my code:

```
<td> <button type="submit" id="@item.Id" name="@item.Id" value="@item.Id" onclick="DeleteRow(@item.Id)" >Delete</button></td>
```

and javascript is:

```
<script>
    function DeleteRow(e) {
        var id = e;
        if (confirm("Do You Confirm?!!!") == true) {
            var parent = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
            ajax({
                    url: "/Leader/DeleteArt",
                    data: {
                        id: e,
                    },
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "Json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Success) {
                            alert("it's deleted");
                            parent.remove();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error!");
                    }
            });
        }
        else {}
    }
</script>
```

the row is deleted but the list is not updated and has the deleted record!

how to update the table without reloading the page.

Comment: *"the list is not updated and has the deleted record"* - What list?  The HTML table?  Or is that the "row" you're saying is deleted?  When you debug, what specifically is happening?

Comment: There is no $ in $.ajax is it a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

You should to create extra function with GET method and replace result with deleted row:

Your delete function:

```
    <script>
        function DeleteRow(e) {
            var id = e;
            if (confirm("Do You Confirm?!!!") == true) {
                var parent = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
                ajax({
                        url: "/Leader/DeleteArt",
                        data: {
                            id: e,
                        },
                        type: "Post",
                        dataType: "Json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.Success) {
                                alert("it's deleted");
                                GetAndReplaceData(id);
                                //parent.remove();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error!");
                        }
                });
            }
            else {}
        }

function GetAndReplaceData(rowID)
    {
    $.get("/Leader/GetArt", function(data, status){
            var rowId = rowID;
            rowId.val("");
            rowId.val(result);

        });
    }
    </script>
```

Instead of .val() function you can use .html()